# Strange issue with Twig's include tag and parameters passed in using the 'with' keyword

Tags: twig, symfony

I have a file, `fileA.html.twig`, which has this include tag:

```
{% include 'templates/fileB.html.twig' with {
    'foo': 'bar'
} %}
```

In `fileB.html.twig`, I have this line

```
<p>{{ foo }}</p>
```

If I try to render `fileA`, I get this error message:

> Variable "foo" does not exist in templates/fileB.html.twig at line 1

Change `fileB.html.twig` to this, however:

```
<p>{{ foo|default('WHAT IS GOING ON HERE?') }}</p>
```

and the template renders and outputs

```
<p>bar</p>
```

So... the variable doesn't exist, supposedly, but if you account for that, and provide a default value, then the variable exists anyway, since its value gets used?

What's going on here? I'm using Symfony 3.1.2.

Comment: Clear your Twig cache and try again. Does it work better?

Comment: Makes virtually no difference. Only thing that changed was that a ':' was added before "templates" in the error message on the first refresh. The cache shouldn't really make a difference here; I'm running in the 'dev' environment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not including `fileB.html.twig` anywhere else that's hidden? Scan your HTML source code for "WHAT IS GOING ON HERE?" when the default is active or see the Symfony Profiler panel "Twig" to debug if it's included more than once.